# iOS simulator is running slowly

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

When I was debugging with Xcode, iOS simulator is running slowly.
I encounter this issue every month, but I cannot find a step for reproduction. 
This issue occurred when I debug my project though, I cannot provide the project, because it is our company’s property.
I recorded this on following URL.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAaclHi_vfE&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like 'slow animations' is enabled. You can disable this in the simulator, top bar, Debug > Toggle Slow Animations

Comment: Yes, thing like that, but I swear I didn’t enable it (It may be enabled automatically).

Comment: You hit the key combination cmd+shift twice

Comment: It could be the Answer, Thank you!